# piping two sax parsers?

Tags: xml, sax, canonicalization

I have the following implementation task and I have no good idea how to solve it.

We have a **SAX-based syntax-checker** for a xml format that checks a hashsum in some closing endElement(). This **hashsum** is built using a kind of **filtering InputStream** that updates a MessageDigest while reading the content. The SAX-syntaxchecker uses this inputstream as its InputSource.

The problem (my task) is, that the hashsum should be built over some **canonicalized parts** of the input xml (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n).

Now the tricky thing: We have a **Canonicalizer that also uses SAX** to canonicalize the input. (It needs to be aware of the current context to distinguish between attributes and nodes etc, thats why we use SAX)

I want to reuse that Canonicalizer but I see no way how to combine these two SAX-parsers.

I think I want some kind of pipelining:

InputFile -> Canonicalizer -> HashCalculation-InputStream -> SyntaxChecker.

Any ideas/references how to accomplish that? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hash calculation reads from an input stream, the result of the canonicalization must eventually be presented as an input stream. You could use a PipedInputStream connected to a PipedOutputStream, or a pair of ByteArrayOutputStream / ByteArrayInputStream over a temporary byte array.

Instead, if the two components were designed with pipe lining in mind, you could have used an `org.xml.sax.XmlFilter`to connect the events from the canonicalizer with the handler of hash calculation/syntax checker

Comment: I was looking for an architecture like this: (http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/xsect/1.022/apidocs/xsect/iaik/xml/filter/impl/dsig/package-summary.html) but for license-reasons, I fall back to ByteArrayOut -> ByteArrayIn. See also (http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html) for a concise description of various ways for piping streams in java.